# Audi A8 adaptive suspension

Tags: suspension, audi

Can't find a sensor for my adaptive air suspension. I have been told mine is overheating causing problem with fault codes. Is it called a different name?

Comment: What's the year or VIN? Have you tried the parts department at the dealer?